# Hibernate transactions are slow

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, transactions

I am writing a spring boot app with hibernate. And being stuck to find out the reason that make my very simple http request returns slowly although the hibernate statistic shows the very fast query execution:

```
    Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_0_, book0_.title as title2_0_ from test.book book0_
    2017-10-01 21:21:17.111  INFO 7727 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
        190864 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
        0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
        24576 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
        6171282 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
        3812491 nanoseconds spent performing 12244 L2C puts;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
        0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
        0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
        4315 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
    }
```

normally, my rest requests take 50ms for the response. but execution and fetching time are very fast ~10ms
Here is my code: (very simple)

BookResource:

```
    public class BookResource {
        @GetMapping("/books")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> findAll() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(postService.findAll());
        }
    }
```

BookService:

```
    @Service
    public class BookService {
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public List<Book> findAll() {
            return bookRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

BookRepository:

```
    public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
    }
```

Book:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "book")
    @Data
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    public class Book {
        @Id
        private Integer id;
        private String title;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which `DataSource` are you using? How much data (records) are you retrieving? Which cache provider are you using? The fact that your query is fast doesn't mean a thing, that query result needs to be transformed into objects, in your case it will also add overhead for caching etc.

Comment: I am using Mysql on localhost with Hikari, the query retrive about 12000 records which can be archived ~ few milliseconds from Mysql Workbench. The fetching operation or transforming to DTO and Json String are very fast I belive

Comment: Comparing plain SQL execution and added overhead from java is never a fair comparison. Don't compare apples and oranges. Also as stated creating 12000 adds overhead, as well as caching those 12000 objects. If each object creation takes 0.005ms it already adds up.

Comment: I'm rather lost. You write that Hibernate transactions are slow, but they take just 10 ms, right? You consider the request taking 50 ms is slow, right? You're curious where the 40 ms difference gets spend, right? +++ It this the first execution if the query or is it the steady state?

Comment: 10ms is just the time to fetch data to the ResultSet, and the transaction takes ~ 35-40ms, ~50 ms for response. When I use native quey, still ~10 for ResultSet but transaction takes only ~20ms, and then ~30ms for response.

Comment: They are the average time I had counted without the first hit to server. I made a apache benchmark test for two of them (5000 request and 10 concurrent connections). Using hibernate takes 162ms and native query takes 72ms for average response. I am worry about using hibernate under the heavy load production and trying to optimize it.

When I turn on hibernate logging, I see loading Entities Operation from ResultSet, and Loading Entities's References in TwoPhaseLoad class. I am suspecting this is the cause make hibernate slow, and finding the way to disable it.